Algebraic set of irreducible polynomial is irreducible?
I'm going through Fulton's Algebraic Curves, and just completed an exercise showing that $V(Y-X^2)$ is irreducible. My solution for this was to show that $Y-X^2$ is irreducible in $k[X,Y]$ (by showing that its quotient ring is $k[X]$, i.e. an integral domain), by which it follows that any polynomial that shares a zero with $Y-X^2$ is necessarily divided evenly by $Y-X^2$, so that $I(V(Y-X^2))$ is prime.
Unless I've done something wrong, this would extend to say that any algebraic set of an irreducible polynomial is itself irreducible? Is this correct?
Thanks in advance!

Yes. $V(I)$ is irreducible if $I$ is a prime ideal.

@LukasHeger thanks! That doesn't follow directly from what I noted down above, correct? I also assume that the equality $J=I(V(J))$ doesn't hold even if $J$ is a prime ideal (like it does above in the case of $J$ being generated by a single irreducible polynomial)?

By the Nullstellensatz for any ideal $I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}$. Now if $J$ is prime, then $J=\sqrt{J}$
